# Achieve color picker in Office ribbon control

Tags: c#, powerpoint, ribbon, office-2013

I'm developing my first add in in Sharepoint for office 2013.

I cant find a way to add a color picker without opening a dialogue box.

I want the color picker in the ribbon, like in the MS-Paint.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no such control. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) does provide a limited set of controls that you can use for custom UI in Office add-in. You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up updating the designer.cs class. adding the required buttons via code in `constructor`.

Comment: Hello. I am a little late to the party, but is it possible to provide some code for the solution that you have used?

Comment: open up your designer.cs file add the control. or if its unclear post a questio, i will try to answer.